# Uncaught ReferenceError: axios is not defined in Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am creating a SPA application with reference to the following tutorial.

http://voerro.com/en/tutorials/r/building-spas-with-laravel-5-and-vuejs-2/1

Until yesterday The top page displayed without error.
But, Today I started virtual machine again and accessed it,
The following javascript error occurs.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: axios is not defined
at new Auth (app.js:53626)
at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:53554)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
at Object.0 (app.js:54214)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
at app.js:84
at app.js:87
```

I tried to review Git's log, but there was not a history that changed.

Do you know how to resolve this??

```
class Auth {
constructor () {
  this.token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
  let userData = window.localStorage.getItem('user');
  this.user = userData ? JSON.parse(userData) : null;

  if (this.token) {
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.token; // <-this is the error point
  }
}

....

export default Auth;
```

app.js

```
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
 import Auth from './auth.js'
 import Api from './api.js';

 window.api = new Api();
 window.auth = new Auth();

 Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

bootstrap.js

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 
'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Comment: You may be able to save time trying to debug this by simply deleting your `node_modules` & `public/js` directories, followed by `npm install` & `npm run dev`.

Comment: Thank you for responding.I tried npm install & npm run dev but it did not work. I also tried npm install axios & npm run dev, but it didn't work too.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. That's weird it just stops working though. Double check to make sure you didnt make a change to the code on accident. Also, you could always try running a `vagrant reload --provision`  and retry compiling your assets. Also, if you are to reinstall/recompile, do it from inside the VM box.

Comment: Is bootstrap.js running before you load auth.js? If not axios is not defined globally before it is used

Comment: @LLai thank you for nice information.I didn't know that. but bootstrap.js was called before axios was used.

Comment: @MattWohler thanks. I do not know why, but I solved it with vagrant reload --provision. Anyway Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Either use `window.axios` or `import axios from 'axios'` or `vue.prototype.$axios = axios`. It's a scoping issue. Don't rely on globals.

Answer (score 1):

I realized the problem was caused due to commenting out or removing

```
require('./bootstrap'); /****in app.js ***/
```

That is if you are working with Vue in Laravel.

**Note**: This is not twitter Bootstrap for UI

Comment: i didn't even think it is not twitter bootstrap and just commented it out, u're a life saver!